# VMWARE - Why can't I find the vmware-tools ISO for linux guest?

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, vmware-tools

In [their website](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1036810) vmware claims that if we are "Unable to locate the ISO image for the VMware Tools installation" then we can just download it. I followed the link indicated and I can find ISO's for the case where the guest is Windows. But what I need is an ISO for the case when the guest is linux (Ubuntu). Where are the ISOs?

Answer (score 1):

They are certainly there. Just have a look at this page: http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/index.html

That is a subdirectory of the site linked to by VMWare and certainly does not just have Windows.

Comment: That site does not include an .iso file for easy installation. For ubuntu it has a bunch of .debs, and it's unclear what they want to do with them (install all? Some? Import as apt-source?). There seems to be no .iso on that site whatsoever...